# `glossaries` 'one off' lowercase full print out

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary acronym entry like this: `\newacronym{mae}{MAE}{My Acronym Entry}`

I have three requirements:

1. In the **Acronyms** list I would like it to print: `My Acronym Entry`
2. For most cases, when I use `\gls{mae}` I would like it to print: `MAE`
3. In *some* cases, when I use `\gls{mae}` I would like it to print: `my acronym entry`

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{mae}{MAE}{My Acronym Entry}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\begin{itemize}
    \item First use: \gls{mae}
    \item Second use: \gls{mae}
    \item Long use: \acrlong{mae}
    \item Lower case use: ??
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I know how to handle the first two requirements. How do I handle the third?

Comment: MWE would be helpful. There is as a command `\acrlong{}`, that diplays long form, then you need to use `\lower` or `\MakeLowerCase{}` or other ..case command. I can try that, but it would be most helpful to prepare example, that I can just copy-paste... Most probably, you will have to deal with expansion (something like `\newcommand{\myacrlower}[1]{\expandafter\MakeLowerCase{\gls{#1}}}`

Comment: @TomášKruliš I added an MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an 'user' field to specifiy your desired format along with the definition of your entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym,automake]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym[user1={my acronym entry}]{mae}{MAE}{My Acronym Entry}

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

    \begin{itemize}
        \item First use: \gls{mae}
        \item Second use: \gls{mae}
        \item Long use: \acrlong{mae}
        \item Lower case use: \glsuseri{mae}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```